# How to mimic PreparedStatement to produce a valid SQL query (Sql#withBatch)

Tags: sql, groovy, batch-file, prepared-statement

Here is my code:

```
// my SQL query used with PreparedStatement before
def query = "INSERT INTO TAB_A (x,y) VALUES (?,?)

Sql myDb = Sql.newInstance(...)


myDb.withBatch(10000, {stmt ->
  // I get parameters as an array
  def params = getParams();

  String rowQuery = funcThatMimicsPrepStat(query, params)

  stmt.addBatch(rowQuery);  
}
```

I currently looking for a way to miminc preparedstatement (*funcThatMimicsPrepStat*) inside withBatch, which works only with Statement. Any advice more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy 1.8.0 doesn't support it yet but it looks like one of the next minor versions will support it. The [trunk source code](https://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/sql/Sql.java) has a couple of examples that are really helpful. Here's one example that uses a `PreparedStatement`:

```
def updateCounts = sql.withBatch(20, 'insert into TABLENAME(a, b, c) values (?, ?, ?)') { ps ->
    ps.addBatch(10, 12, 5) // varargs style
    ps.addBatch([7, 3, 98]) // list
    ps.addBatch([22, 67, 11])
    ...
}
```

I guess you could either snatch that piece of code or wait for a Groovy 1.8.x release.

Comment: Thx! It is exactly what I am looking for. I will mark it as the answer as soon as I manage to run it in my program.

Comment: Groovy 1.8.1-SNAPSHOT supports preparedstatements in withBatch: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.8.1-SNAPSHOT/